# Reset multiple UserControl's properties at once

Tags: vb.net, properties, user-controls, visual-studio-2017

I want to use this `Sub` so to reset at once some `UserControl`'s properties. As it is, resets only `BackColor` value of my `UserControl`. How can I "convert" it so to resets more than one property?

```
Private Sub ResetControl(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim _UserControl As UserControl1 = CType(Me.Control, UserControl1)
    Dim _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_UserControl)("BackColor")
    _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_UserControl)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get all properties and execute this for each of them

> ```
>     For Each OneProperty In _UserControl.GetType.GetProperties()
>         Dim _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_UserControl)(OneProperty.Name)
>         If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(_UserControl) AndAlso _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_UserControl) IsNot Nothing Then
>             _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_UserControl)
>         End If
>     Next
> ```

or from list of string if u wanna use names

> ```
>     Dim ListOfPropertyNames As New List(Of String) From {"BackColor", "BorderStyle", "Dock"}
>     For Each OneProperty In ListOfPropertyNames
>         Dim _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_UserControl)(OneProperty)
>         If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(_UserControl) Then ' this return tru if can be reset
>             If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_UserControl) IsNot Nothing Then ' check value if is not  nothing
>                 _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_UserControl)
>             End If
>         End If
>     Next
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, I used your second example because this is what I was wanted to do... Just take a look at your first example, because it gives me this error `Error invoking 'Reset Control'. Details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: looks like something is nothing or empty i hop simple check can help u , edited 2 sample, what property name u wanna reset  that make u this problem

Comment: ther is also CanResetValue method so u can skip if is imposible

Comment: @Nobert: Your **second** example is **working perfect**. You just have to edit your example and replace `Is Nothing` with `IsNot Nothing`. :)

Your first example is still giving me the same error!!! I also tried to use it with `If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue` and `If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_UserControl) IsNot Nothing` from your second example but nothing...

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it for certain properties, you can use an array:

```
Private Sub ResetControl(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim _UserControl As UserControl1 = CType(Me.Control, UserControl1)

    Dim _PropertyDescriptors As PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_UserControl)
    For Each propertyName as String in {"BackColor", "ForeColor"}
        _PropertyDescriptors(propertyName).ResetValue(_UserControl)
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I get this two errors `Value of type 'PropertyDescriptorCollection' cannot be converted to 'PropertyDescriptor'.` and `Class 'PropertyDescriptor' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.`.

Comment: typo fixed above

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer my friend!!! Your example is working too but I'll accept Nobert's answer as correct just because he answered first. Please take a look at your example. I edited your code. I added an `if` `CanResetValue` and an `if` `IsNot Nothing`. I think they are both necessary.